# MVC Model Custom Validation on IList

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, validation, model, data-annotations, customvalidator

I have an IList attribute in my Model. I need to write a custom validation for that attribute (list)count which must be Greater than two.

```
public IList<AccountAddress> BulkOrderAddresses { get; set; }
```

Please help me....

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could implement [IValidatableObject Interface](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.ivalidatableobject.aspx)

Something like this:

```
public class MyObject : IValidatableObject
{
     public IList<AccountAddress> BulkOrderAddresses { get; set; }

     public IEnumerable<ValidationResult> Validate(ValidationContext validationContext)
     {
          if(BulkOrderAddresses == null && !BulkOrderAddresses.Length > 2)
          {
               yield return new ValidationResult("List should contain more than 2 items");
          }
     }
}
```